# How to access a dynamic object property not using getter method?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

class SomeClass
{
 public: int *SomeNumber;

 SomeClass() { SomeNumber = new int; *SomeNumber = 5; }

 ~SomeClass() { delete SomeNumber; }
 int getSomeNumber(void) { return *SomeNumber; }

};

int main()
{

SomeClass A;
std:: cout << A.getSomeNumber() << std::endl; // outputs 5
std:: cout << A.SomeNumber << std::endl; // outputs SomeNumber address

return 0;
}
```

How can I get *SomeNumber, not its address, by not using the method getSomeNumber()? If SomeNumber were not a pointer to a int, I could get it with A.SomeNumber

Sorry If I were not clear enough.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are missing an assignment operator and copy constructor.

Comment: @pmr: And a copy constructor. See [The Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three).

Comment: @pmr: Darn! Did I really post this within your 5mins edit period? I fell for a stupid beginner's prank... `:)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple:

```
*A.SomeNumber
```

It works because `.` has higher precedence than `*`, so it's the same as

```
*(A.SomeNumber)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just do:

```
std:: cout << (*A.SomeNumber) << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid making your properties public!!!!

You could use visitor design pattern instead of this code like:

```
class SomeClass
{
 public: int *SomeNumber;

 SomeClass() { SomeNumber = new int; *SomeNumber = 5; }

 void visit( IVisitor* visitor ){ visitor->doSomething(*SomeNumber);}

 ~SomeClass() { delete SomeNumber; }
 int getSomeNumber(void) { return *SomeNumber; }

};
```

IVisitor is an interface you can implement it and anything you want.

Comment: Maybe this toy example needs a SomeNumberFactory too, and a Decorator, and a dependency injection framework!

Comment: I am pretty sure that public member is a bad chose in any case.

Comment: @Thomas: You're forgetting an abstract wrapper and multiple dispatch. Call yourself a software developer...

Comment: getter setters are bad chose too.